# secure upload executable file and maintain confidentiality of files

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I'm php programer and familiar to secur file upload such as:

1- Do not place the .htaccess file in the same directory where the uploaded files will be stored. It should be placed in the parent directory.

2-If possible, upload the files in a directory outside the server root.

3-Prevent overwriting of existing files (to prevent the .htaccess overwrite attack).

4-Create a list of accepted mime-types (map extensions from these mime types).

5-Generate a random file name and add the previously generated extension.

6-Don’t rely on client-side validation only, since it is not enough. Ideally one should have both server-side and client-side validation implemented.

8-check mime type and file name and extevtion of file, also store hash of file and..... and other tips base on this links:

1-http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/

2-https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

but I have web site that users can upload mal file or exe file To the experts examine the file .also confidentiality of files is important.

so this file have two restriction: 1- users can upload mal file or exe file 2-theese file are secret and should have good protection i storage(To maintain confidentiality)

my solution is:

1- I force users to send the zip file .and the program pload the files in a directory outside the server root.. This restriction is sufficient?

2- To maintain confidentiality of files.how can store some section of file in database and other section in the file system stored on the file system. In order to , if the hacker compromise the server will not be able to abtain hole file data?

Comment: Instead of splitting a file up to protect against possible breach, it would be a better approach to use encryption.

Comment: if someone compromises your server, they probably have access to everything they need to decrypt your files!
Encryption is only going to save you if an attacker somehow gets access to your file storage directory, but nothing else on the server. That's a very unlikely scenario.
.but if split files in database and filesystem ,if the hacker compromise the server will not be able to obtain all file data easily?

Comment: The only thing you accomplish is a minor slowdown; they have to download the files and the database ... doesn't seem worth the effort imho.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a cross post of http://security.stackexchange.com/q/56788/8340

Answer (score 1):

> 1- I force users to send the zip file .and the program pload the files in a directory outside the server root.. This restriction is sufficient?

How would you enforce this? Checking the file extension? Trusting user-provided headers? Parsing the file and guessing its MIME type?

> 2- To maintain confidentiality of files.how can store some section of file in database and other section in the file system stored on the file system. In order to , if the hacker compromise the server will not be able to abtain hole file data?

This won't buy you much. If an attacker can compromise your systems, they can get the database password from the same disk as half the file, and thereby recover the whole file.

A much better idea would be to pass the files' contents to a separate server (e.g. an Amazon S3 bucket) and serve your files from a different domain name.

> but I have web site that users can upload mal file or exe file To the experts examine the file .also confidentiality of files is important.

Is this for someting like [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/)?